# How to make python script execute on click?

Tags: python, executable

I'm trying to run a python file solely as a program so it just opens the command line for the user when they click on the file. However the only way that is working to execute the file is through the command line. Iv'e read about changing the permissions with chmod, but when I run it through the command prompt, it comes back saying chmod isn't recognized as an internal or external command. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: And what happens when you double-click a Python script in File Explorer (it sounds like you're on Windows)?

Comment: What operating system are you running, Windows or Linux?

Comment: If you give it `+x` with chmod and use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3` or whatever version you use at the top of the script, it will be openable with a click

Comment: @GáborErdős - OP said that `chmod` produces "isn't recognized as an internal or external command," which means Windows, not Linux.

Comment: Um is a python script just a text doc with different file etension? Can you write a batch and reference it in registry assuming windows.

Comment: I'm using Windows, and I changed python files to open with Sublime Text so it opens there.

Comment: Well, change it back.

Comment: Did you try right-click open-with: <your python interpreter>?

Comment: I changed it back to open with python but now it flashes the command window and then disappears.

Comment: That' normal. The program starts in console, which is closed after termination of your python program.

Comment: So how would I allow the user to see the output of the console?

Comment: Either run it through the command prompt like you've been doing, add an `input()` call to the end of the script so you have to press Enter before it completes, or make a batch file that runs your script and then has a pause.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 according to Wikipedia it says it is specific to Unix like systems so not sure why not work for you

Comment: @marshalcraft Correct, but the problem appeared on a windows system and is not a permission problem, at all.

Comment: Would it help if I opened a tkinter window because I was thinking about incorporating it anyways

Comment: Also, I'm worried that if I share it with others they won't be able to execute it if they don't have the Python interpreter.